# How to use FFmpeg to replace the silents(which more than 110ms) of audio with other duration(400ms) silent

Tags: ffmpeg

If the silent of audio is more than 110ms, replace them to 400ms.

How to use FFmpeg to do that?

Answer (score 1):

heavy script:

```
#!/bin/bash

INP="input.mp3"
EMP="empty400ms.mp3"
OUT="output.mp3"
SDP="-60dB:d=0.110"

SIL=($(ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "$INP" -af "silencedetect=$SDP" -f null - 2>&1 | grep "\[silencedetect" | awk '{print $NF}'))
FFC="list.txt"
echo "ffconcat version 1.0" > $FFC
ITS="0.000"
for ((i=0; i<${#SIL[@]}; i+=2)); do
  BEG=${SIL[$i]}   #silence_start
  DUR=${SIL[$i+1]} #silence_duration
  echo $BEG + $DUR
  if (($(echo "$DUR > 0.110" | bc))); then
    if (($(echo "$DUR < 0.400" | bc))); then
      ITS=$(echo "print $ITS" | perl)
      echo "file '$INP'" >> $FFC
      echo "inpoint $ITS" >> $FFC
      echo "outpoint $BEG" >> $FFC
      echo "file '$EMP'" >> $FFC
    else
      ITS=$(echo "print $ITS" | perl)
      OTS=$(echo "print $BEG + 0.400" | perl)
      echo "file '$INP'" >> $FFC
      echo "inpoint $ITS" >> $FFC
      echo "outpoint $OTS" >> $FFC
      if [[ ! -f "$EMP" ]]; then
        ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -ss $BEG -t 0.400 -i "$INP" -c copy "$EMP"
      fi
    fi
    ITS=$(echo "$BEG + $DUR" | bc)
  fi
done
echo "file '$INP'" >> $FFC
echo "inpoint $ITS" >> $FFC

echo -----
cat $FFC
echo -----
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy "$OUT" -y -hide_banner
echo -----
mpv "$OUT"
echo -----
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "$OUT" -af "silencedetect=$SDP" -f null -
```

empty400ms.mp3 can be created by next script

```
#!/bin/bash

f="input.mp3"
o="empty400ms.mp3"
IFS=, read -r CN0 SR0 CH0 CL0 BR0 < <(ffprobe -v 0 -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name,sample_rate,channels,channel_layout,bit_rate -of csv=p=0 "$f")
echo $CN0 $SR0 $CH0 $CL0 $BR0
EXP="0"
for ((i=1; i<$CH0; i++)); do
  EXP+="|0"
done
ffmpeg -lavfi "aevalsrc=${EXP}:c='${CL0}':d=0.400:s=${SR0}" -b:a $BR0 "$o" -y
```

Comment: does it help to first use something like `loudnorm` or `dynaudnorm` to equalize the volume before applying the `silencedetect` filter, or does it not matter ?

Comment: it depends of source. imho `loudnorm` will increase volume of noise in silence. maybe, not.

Comment: which may be advantageous if the goal is to identify unwanted silence gaps, and we could also identify the sections with trace amounts of background white noise.